# Applying conditional formatting from cells being called into another sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a way in VBA that I can format each cell in one sheet of my workbook based off of the cell formatting of a cell in another sheet?

In one of my sheets, I have a conditional format that changes the color of the cell based off a formula. I want to use VBA to copy the cell's color into a separate sheet's cell. I tried to use Format Painter but it was copying the conditional format's equation when all I need is the color of the cell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PasteSpecial Formats

[image]

Copy a whole worksheet's formats

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Copy a range's formats

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```